# How to match unique elements in one column and list the corresponding values from second column

Tags: python, r, unix, text, bioinformatics

I have a file in the following format:

```
ENSG00000087510  ENST00000201031  TFAP2C  transcription_factor  protein_coding
```

Where each column is separated by a tab.

As you can see, there are 5 columns. Column 1 is a list of redundant IDs each matching to another unique ID in column 2. The redundant IDs in column 1 are scattered all over the file.

I tried the following command to generate a unique list of IDs from the first column but I don't know how to match it with the second column.

`cat Chr20_gene_transcript_namelist.txt | cut -f 1 | sort | uniq`

I want a file of two columns: the unique IDs in column 1 with all the IDs they match to in column 2.

Eg:

```
ENSG00000087510  ENST00000201031
                 ENST00000202017
                 ENST00000217133
ENSG00000100983  ENST00000217131
                 ENST00000217246
                 ENST00000237527
ENSG00000132823  ENST00000255174
```

Comment: I hope this is better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in bash, but since you used the python tag, here is a script that should work:

```
with open(<your_file>, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

id_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    elems = line.split()
    if elems[0] in id_dict:
        id_dict[elems[0]].append(elems[1])
    else:
        id_dict[elems[0]] = [elems[1]]

with open(<your_output_file>, 'w') as f:
    for redundant_id, unique_ids in id_dict.items():
        f.write('%s\t%s\n' % (redundant_id, unique_ids[0]))
        for unique_id in unique_ids[1:]:
            f.write('\t%s\n' % unique_id)
```